# How to return HTTP 207 Multi Status with javax.ws.rs.core (jersey-core-1.17.1.jar)

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

`Response.java` of `javax.ws.rs.core` which is available in `jersey-core-1.17.1.jar` doesn't have `HTTP status 207` (Multi Status).

If i want to return `HTTP 207 status` with Multi Status as message, how can I achieve jersey?

Am I need to customize the jar? if yes, what are the java files need to be modified?

Is there any other version of jersey-core jar available with `HTTP status 207`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ResponseBuilder with

```
ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status( 207 );
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. I have customized Response class by keeping MULTI_STATUS(207, "Multi Status"). I could able to get status code 207 in response but message is getting as "unknown" instead of "Multi Status". Please suggest.

Comment: Right, if you use `Response.status(int)` then you have no text for that status. Extending the Response class and building your own Jersey version is certainly fine.